# POSTMAN POST Request Returns Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, postman

I am following the API instructions from Adam Freeman's "Pro ASP.NET Core MVC 2". I have the following API controller class:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ReservationController : Controller
    {
        private IRepository repository;

    public ReservationController(IRepository repo) => repository = repo;

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Reservation> Get() => repository.Reservations;

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Reservation Get(int id) => repository[id];

    [HttpPost]
    public Reservation Post([FromBody] Reservation res) =>
        repository.AddReservation(new Reservation
        {
            ClientName = res.ClientName,
            Location = res.Location
        });

    [HttpPut]
    public Reservation Put([FromBody] Reservation res) => repository.UpdateReservation(res);

    [HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public StatusCodeResult Patch(int id, [FromBody]JsonPatchDocument<Reservation> patch)
    {
        Reservation res = Get(id);
        if(res != null)
        {
            patch.ApplyTo(res);
            return Ok();
        }
        return NotFound();
    }

    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public void Delete(int id) => repository.DeleteReservation(id);
}
```

The text uses PowerShell to test the API but I would like to use Postman. In Postman, the GET call works. However, I cannot get the POST method to return a value. The error reads 'Status Code: 415; Unsupported Media Type'

In Postman, the Body uses form-data, with:

```
key: ClientName, value: Anne
key: Location, value: Meeting Room 4
```

If I select the Type dropdown to "JSON", it reads "Unexpected 'S'"

In the Headers, I have:

```
`key: Content-Type, value: application/json`
```

I have also tried the following raw data in the body, rather than form data:

```
{clientName="Anne"; location="Meeting Room 4"}
```

The API controller does work and return correct values when I use PowerShell. For the POST method, the following works:

```
Invoke-RestMethod http://localhost:7000/api/reservation -Method POST -Body (@{clientName="Anne"; location="Meeting Room 4"} | ConvertTo-Json) -ContentType "application/json"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using Postman with POST and JSON body you'll have to use the `raw` data entry and set it to `application/json` and data would be like this:

```
{"clientName":"Anne", "location":"Meeting Room 4"}
```

Note how both key and value are quoted.

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but I still have the same error. In Postmans `Body`, I used raw and the quotations as you've shown. In the 'Headers' I am using the `Content-Type` key with `JSON(application/json)` as the value.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Thanks for noting that, didn't notice the =. Fixed answer accordingly.

Comment: @KirkLarkin, sorry you edited your comment before I could post. I've tried what you suggest and still get the same error

Comment: @coolhand you don't have to manually add the header value, either remove it, or set the value to `application/json`  the JSON(application/json) is the box in Postman when you're entering raw data

Comment: maybe this comments can be included in the answer for next persons that finds this problem

Comment: How to i test uploading a file with postman in this situation?

Comment: Uploading a file generally requires you to use the _Binary_ body type, but is out of scope for this question @JohanVanWambeke